# Why aren't some of my extensions enabled when I open a VS Code remote workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I opened a [remote SSH workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) in VSCode and some of my extensions aren't enabled. For example, I have the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and [Go](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.Go) extensions installed but when I connect to my remote ssh workspace they don't work. The same also happens in remote workspaces that use dev containers or WSL.

How do I enable these extensions in my remote workspaces?

Answer (score 8):

When you open a remote workspace, VS Code runs extensions in one of two places:

- Themes and other **UI extensions** are run on your local machine.
- Language extensions and other more advanced, **workspace extensions** are run on the remote machine.

UI extensions are enabled by default when you open a remote workspace, but the workspace extensions must be installed on the remote itself. That is why you do not see Python and Go enabled by default in the remote workspace.

---

**To install a locally installed extension on a remote machine:**

1. Open the remote workspace and open the Extensions view. The top section of the extension lists contains that are already installed on the remote (also indicated by the `><` badge on the extension entries) , while the `Local — Installed` section shows local UI extensions along with the workspace extensions that are not yet installed on the remote.

   [image: Extension install locations]
2. In the `Local — Installed` section, scroll down to see the workspace extensions that are not yet installed on the remote. These are faded out and have a green install button next to them. Here the `VS Code Speech` is a UI extension that is running locally while the `Angular Language Service` is a workspace extension installed locally but that has not yet been installed on the remote:

   [image: Extension install button]
3. Use the green install button to install each workspace extension you wish to enable in the remote workspace. Then reload the window.

---

You can also **configure a list of extensions that should be auto installed** on SSH or dev container remotes by setting:

```
"remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": [
    "eamodio.gitlens",
    "mutantdino.resourcemonitor"
],
"remote.containers.defaultExtensions": [
    "eamodio.gitlens",
    "mutantdino.resourcemonitor"
]
```

These settings take a list of extensions IDs on each extension's details page in the top right, next to the extension name:

[image: The extension ID is to the right of the extension name]

Comment: I'm wondering if the settings mentioned here, e.g. `"remote.SSH.defaultExtensions"`, were removed.  They have no effect for me, and they are being flagged as unknown configuration strings.

Comment: @kip these only work on user level, not project level

Comment: to get the extension id i had to press on the cogwheel on the extension's detail page and select copy extension id